# SED Replace multiple second occurrence of a character

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have .srt files which are in the following format:

```
0
1
00:00:01,830 --> 00:00:04,740
corresponding text
1

2
00:00:05,280 --> 00:00:10,280
corresponding text
2

3
00:00:10,740 --> 00:00:14,640
corresponding text
3

4
00:00:15,510 --> 00:00:19,260
corresponding text
4
```

and that extra line with the line number is all the way through the subtitle (line 5, line 6...line 540).
I tried the command `sed '/^[0-9]/ s/.//'` and as expected it replaces all the numbers, but I don't know how to make it replace only the second occurrence of each number in the range.

The expected result is:

```
0
1
00:00:01,830 --> 00:00:04,740
corresponding text

2
00:00:05,280 --> 00:00:10,280
corresponding text

3
00:00:10,740 --> 00:00:14,640
corresponding text

4
00:00:15,510 --> 00:00:19,260
corresponding text
```

How can I achieve it either with sed, awk or any tool that can do it in batches since there are several files with the same situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`, you can set a variable whenever the line contains one field. If it does, use a variable to hold the last value of that field, and skip printing the line when they match.

```
awk 'NF == 1 {if (num != "" && $0 == num) next; else num = $0} 1'
```

Comment: Thanks!

Works great.

I would really appreciate an explanation of how it works

EDIT: For some reason 1 to 4 works fine, 5 remain doubled, and from 6 to the end it works fine again

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=RS;RS=""} {$NF=""}1' file
0
1
00:00:01,830 --> 00:00:04,740
corresponding text

2
00:00:05,280 --> 00:00:10,280
corresponding text

3
00:00:10,740 --> 00:00:14,640
corresponding text

4
00:00:15,510 --> 00:00:19,260
corresponding text
```

Comment: Huh??? WTF? Ed... ?? What on earth is happening here?? (clueless, but I gotta know...) Why default print everything with a rule `$NF=""`?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - yes, that makes sense. I had snapped to most of that but did not catch the effect of `$NF=""` -- thinking about it in terms of paragraph and nuking the last field makes perfect sense.

Comment: Right, it's just emptying the last line (field) of each block (record/paragraph) then printing the block.

Comment: I don't know why, but it doesn't work for me. It only removes the last duplicate of the file

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it for what's causing that and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

direct translation of your description.  Remove the duplicate number appearing standalone of the line.  Print if not integer, otherwise print only the first instance.

```
$ awk 'int($0)!=$0 || !a[$0]++' file

0
1
00:00:01,830 --> 00:00:04,740
corresponding text

2
00:00:05,280 --> 00:00:10,280
corresponding text

3
00:00:10,740 --> 00:00:14,640
corresponding text

4
00:00:15,510 --> 00:00:19,260
corresponding text
```

Comment: I have the same problem as with the most voted answer, it only removes the last duplicate of the file and i dont know why

Comment: Can you test with the sample input file you posted at the question (copy from the question please)?  Then we'll know whether it's the scripts or your actual input file is the culprit.

Comment: Apparently it's the file...when I check the file with ```file``` it says ```ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators```

Comment: Use `dos2unix` to remove the CR characters, Unix text files should just use LF as the line terminator.